# Does shorting stock cause your account value to go up?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, brokerage

Does shorting stock cause your account value number to go up?

Specifically for IB but most broker have a number that shows the total value of your account

Stocks + cash + any other investment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shorting a stock increases the amount of cash in your account but it does not increase the value of your account because there is an offsetting short position whose value is negative (you must buy it back to close it).